# Trying to overload<< class function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm trying to overload operator<< on function. I'm stuck for a few solid hours trying to figure this out. I have found a lot of examples how to do this on ostream but none of them targeted my specific problem.

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
   foo& operator<< (foo& (*pf)(foo&))
   {
     return pf(*this);
   }
   foo& do_something_more(foo& os)
   {
     return os;
   }
};

ostream& do_something(ostream& os)
{
   os << "1." << "\n" << "2.";
   return os;
}

int main()
{
    foo a;

    std::cout << do_something; // this works
    a << do_something_more; // this do not

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is just one example how I tried to solve this. I'm getting error *'do_something_more':indeclared identifier* in this one.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `do_something_more()` is a member function of `foo` and you need an instance to call it.

Comment: Or make it static and use `a << foo::do_something_more;`... or just non-member.

Comment: Nothing of that stuff really makes sense.

Comment: _@Norbert_ Did you rather mean to overload the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const foo&)` function?

Comment: I'm looking for exact behavior  `a << do_something_more;`. Edit: ok. I made my function as non-member `friend ostream& do_something(ostream& os)` and this works. I was stuck on this for a lot of hours and answer was so simple. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Where you wrote that `std::cout << do_something;` works, did you mean to say `a << do_something;`?

Answer (score -4):

As the error says, you haven't declared any object called do_something_more. This is a method in your foo class. Try `cout<<a.do_something_more();`

Even with this, I am not sure whether it will work.

Comment: You try it first.